# How to enable a css tag only during hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a `badge` notification using `css`, but I want to show it only during hovering of the outer element. It that possible?

```
<img src..><span class="badge">5</span></img>
```

The badge is created as follows from css:

```
/*@see http://cssdeck.com/labs/menu-with-notification-badges*/
img .badge {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 3px;
  line-height: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);

  background: #67c1ef;
  border-color: #30aae9;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #acddf6, #67c1ef);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #acddf6, #67c1ef);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #acddf6, #67c1ef);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #acddf6, #67c1ef);
}
```

Question: how can I show the badge *only* when hovering the specific `img` where the `badge` class is applied at?

Answer (score 3):

For starters the `img` element is a standalone self-closing element and doesn't doesn't allow children elements. With that markup most browsers will convert your code to:

```
<img src... />
<span class="badge">5</span>
```

Some may also treat that `</img>` tag as a second `img` element.

Separating the `img` element from the `span` as shown above is what we firstly want to do anyway, so adjust your HTML to reflect that. Then we can implement the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) so select our `span` element when the `img` element is being overed over:

```css
img:hover + .badge {
    ...
}
```

Remember to hide the `.badge` element by default.

```css
.badge {
  display: none;
}

img:hover + .badge {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/320x140&text=Hover%20Here" />
<span class="badge">Hello, world!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .hover() function can also do this, remember $(".badge").hide() when load the page.